# The package rxjs@5.0.0-beta.6 does not satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies requirements?

Tags: npm, angular, ngrx

I am trying to install @ngrx/store module in my angular 2 app. I am using npm install and getting the following error:

```
npm ERR! peerinvalid The package rxjs@5.0.0-beta.6 does not satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies requirements!
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer @angular/core@2.0.0-rc.0 wants rxjs@5.0.0-beta.6
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer @angular/http@2.0.0-rc.0 wants rxjs@5.0.0-beta.6
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer angular2@2.0.0-beta.16 wants rxjs@5.0.0-beta.2
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer @ngrx/store@1.5.0 wants rxjs@5.0.0-beta.6
```

Does this mean I have to upgrade my angular2 module because it needs a lower version of rxjs@5.0.0-beta.2?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that you have both beta.16 and rc.0 as dependencies in the same project. Since angular changed the npm package name between the two, you will need to uninstall and remove dependencies on whichever one you don't want. Assuming you want to upgrade to the rc.0, remove it from your package.json and run:

```
npm uninstall angular2
```

Comment: First update npm: 
npm install npm -g
Then, It will work without issues.

Answer (score 3):

I was on node v 0.12 and upgrading to version 6.9 fixed this

Answer (score 1):

Try running this, it might work for you:

`npm install --save @angular/core @angular/compiler @angular/common @angular/platform-browser @angular/platform-browser-dynamic rxjs@5.0.0-beta.6 zone.js@0.6.12`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and just updated to rxjs@5.0.1

```
npm install rxjs@5.0.1 --save
```

That did the trick.