# Unable to install Angular Material in Vs 2015, getting an error

Tags: angular-material

These are the errors coming while installing the material-2

```
F:\AppTy\UIFrame\UIFrame>npm install --save @angular2-material/core @angular2-ma
terial/checkbox
npm WARN package.json angular2-quickstart@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN package.json angular2-quickstart@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json angular2-quickstart@1.0.0 No README data
npm WARN package.json @angular/common@2.0.0-rc.1 No description
npm WARN package.json @angular/common@2.0.0-rc.1 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json @angular/http@2.0.0-rc.0 No description
npm WARN package.json @angular/http@2.0.0-rc.0 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json @angular/http@2.0.0-rc.0 No README data
npm WARN package.json @angular/compiler@2.0.0-rc.1 No description
npm WARN package.json @angular/compiler@2.0.0-rc.1 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json @angular/core@2.0.0-rc.1 No description
npm WARN package.json @angular/core@2.0.0-rc.1 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@2.0.0-rc.1 No descriptio
n
npm WARN package.json @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@2.0.0-rc.1 No repository
 field.
npm WARN package.json @angular/router@2.0.0-rc.1 No description
npm WARN package.json @angular/router@2.0.0-rc.1 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json @angular/platform-browser@2.0.0-rc.1 No description
npm WARN package.json @angular/platform-browser@2.0.0-rc.1 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json @angular/upgrade@2.0.0-rc.1 No description
npm WARN package.json @angular/upgrade@2.0.0-rc.1 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json @angular/router-deprecated@2.0.0-rc.1 No description
npm WARN package.json @angular/router-deprecated@2.0.0-rc.1 No repository field.

npm WARN peerDependencies The peer dependency angular2@^2.0.0-beta.8 included fr
om @angular2-material/checkbox will no
npm WARN peerDependencies longer be automatically installed to fulfill the peerD
ependency
npm WARN peerDependencies in npm 3+. Your application will need to depend on it
explicitly.
npm WARN package.json @angular/core@2.0.0-rc.0 No description
npm WARN package.json @angular/core@2.0.0-rc.0 No repository field.
npm WARN unmet dependency F:\AppTy\UIFrame\UIFrame\node_modules\angular2-in-memo
ry-web-api requires @angular/http@'2.0.0-rc.1' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency F:\AppTy\UIFrame\UIFrame\node_modules\@angular\http,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 2.0.0-rc.0
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.3.9600
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files (
x86)\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "--save" "@angular2-
material/core" "@angular2-material/checkbox"
npm ERR! node v0.12.2
npm ERR! npm  v2.7.4
npm ERR! code EPEERINVALID

npm ERR! peerinvalid The package @angular/core does not satisfy its siblings' pe
erDependencies requirements!
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer @angular/common@2.0.0-rc.1 wants @angular/core@2.0.0-r
c.1
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer @angular/compiler@2.0.0-rc.1 wants @angular/core@2.0.0
-rc.1
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer @angular/http@2.0.0-rc.0 wants @angular/core@2.0.0-rc.
0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer @angular/platform-browser@2.0.0-rc.1 wants @angular/co
re@2.0.0-rc.1
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@2.0.0-rc.1 wants @an
gular/core@2.0.0-rc.1
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer @angular/router@2.0.0-rc.1 wants @angular/core@2.0.0-r
c.1
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer @angular/router-deprecated@2.0.0-rc.1 wants @angular/c
ore@2.0.0-rc.1
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer @angular/upgrade@2.0.0-rc.1 wants @angular/core@2.0.0-
rc.1
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer @angular2-material/core@2.0.0-alpha.4 wants @angular/c
ore@^2.0.0-rc.0

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     F:\AppTy\UIFrame\UIFrame\npm-debug.log

F:\AppTy\UIFrame\UIFrame>
```

Comment: Please copy and paste this information as text, not an image. Thanks

Comment: @halfer i did. Have you any idea about these errors.

Comment: Looks like [someone else has a similar problem](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37111726/472495). No ideas here I'm afraid, I don't use Angular nor Windows.